# Rename multiple filename with random numeric extension after one specific alphanumeric word in Linux

Tags: linux, file-rename

I have a folder/subfolders that contain some files with filenames that end with a random numeric extension:

```
DWH..AUFTRAG.20211123115143.A901.3801176
DWH..AUFTRAGSPOSITION.20211122002147.A901.3798013
```

I would like to remove everything after `A901` from the above filenames.

For example:

`DWH..AUFTRAG.20211123115143.A901` (remove this `.3801176`)
`DWH..AUFTRAGSPOSITION.20211122002147.A901`   (remove this `.3798013`) from the filename

How do I use rename or any other command in linux to remove only after `A901` everything from finale rest file name keep as it is?

Answer (score 0):

I can see there is 5 '.' (dots) before the number so I did some desi jugad.

I made some files in folder and also made a folder and created some files inside that folder accourding to the name pattern that you gave.

I created a command and it somewhat looks like this.

```
find "$PWD"|grep A901|while read F; do mv "${F}" `echo ${F}|cut -d . -f 1-5`;done
```

When executed it worked for me.
terminal output below.

```
rexter@rexter:~/Desktop/test$ find $PWD
/home/rexter/Desktop/test
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/test1
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/test1/DWH..AUFTRAG.20211123115143.A901.43214
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/test1/DWH..AUFTRAGSPOSITION.2021112200fsd2147.A901.31244324
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/DWH..AUFTRAG.20211123115143.A901.321423
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/DWH..AUFTRAGSPOSITION.20211122002147.A901.3124325


rexter@rexter:~/Desktop/test$ find "$PWD"|grep A901|while read F; do mv "${F}" `echo ${F}|cut -d . -f 1-5`;done


rexter@rexter:~/Desktop/test$ find $PWD
/home/rexter/Desktop/test
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/test1
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/test1/DWH..AUFTRAG.20211123115143.A901
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/test1/DWH..AUFTRAGSPOSITION.2021112200fsd2147.A901
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/DWH..AUFTRAG.20211123115143.A901
/home/rexter/Desktop/test/DWH..AUFTRAGSPOSITION.20211122002147.A901
rexter@rexter:~/Desktop/test$
```

I dont know if this is a proper way to do it but it just make things work.

Let me know if it is useful to you.